# Tinymce upload image url in react doesn't work

Tags: javascript, reactjs, tinymce, rich-text-editor, tinymce-5

I am trying to insert image url in my texteditor made in Reactjs and tineymce. But it gives error as:

> `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'nodeName')`

This is my code for editor.

```
export default function DraftEditor() {
  const editorRef = useRef(null);
 
  const example_image_upload_handler = (blobInfo, progress) =>
    new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      const xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
      xhr.withCredentials = false;
      xhr.open(
        "POST",
        "image_upload_url",
        true
      );

      xhr.upload.onprogress = (e) => {
        progress((e.loaded / e.total) * 100);
      };

      xhr.onload = () => {
        if (xhr.status === 403) {
          reject({ message: "HTTP Error: " + xhr.status, remove: true });
          return;
        }

        if (xhr.status < 200 || xhr.status >= 300) {
          reject("HTTP Error: " + xhr.status);
          return;
        }

        const json = JSON.parse(xhr.responseText);

        if (!json || typeof json.data != "string") {
          reject("Invalid JSON: " + xhr.responseText);
          return;
        }

        resolve(json.data);
      };


      const formData = new FormData();
      formData.append("image", blobInfo.blob(), blobInfo.filename());

      xhr.send(formData);
    });
  return (
    <>
      <Editor
        apiKey={process.env.REACT_APP_TINY}
        onInit={(evt, editor) => (editorRef.current = editor)}
        initialValue={``}
        init={{
          images_upload_handler: example_image_upload_handler,
          plugins: [
            "image",
          ],
          image_title: true,
          file_picker_types: "image",
          automatic_uploads: true,
          content_style:
            "body { font-family:Helvetica,Arial,sans-serif; font-size:14px }",
          images_file_types: "jpg,svg,png",
          toolbar: "codesample code",
          content_style:
            "body { font-family: 'Courier New', Courier, monospace; font-size: 0.9em }",
        }}
      />
    </>
  );
}
```

This image upload code is from it's documentation. I am uploading local image to my server and trying to insert the returned link in the editor.

This is my error ss.
[image]